# AngularJS NG-repeat: How to repeat a data inside an ng-repeat that has to filter unique values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on a project that has a JSON data that returns results of information. Basically, the idea is to show these data by using the BootStrap Tabs in which being filtered by the category.

**Mock JSON data:**

```
"result": [
    {
        category: "A",
        price: "499.00",
        productName: "AAA",
        productConfig: {
            specs: "Lorem ipsum",
            creditAllowed: false,
            description: "blah blah",
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        category: "A",
        price: "479.00",
        productName: "AAB",
        productConfig: {
            specs: "Lorem ipsum",
            creditAllowed: true,
            description: "blah blah",
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        category: "B",
        price: "1299.00",
        productName: "BBB",
        productConfig: {
            specs: "Lorem ipsum",
            creditAllowed: true,
            description: "blah blah",
            ...
        }
    },
    {
        category: "A",
        price: "359.00",
        productName: "AXX",
        productConfig: {
            specs: "Lorem ipsum",
            creditAllowed: true,
            description: "blah blah",
            ...
        }
    },
]
```

Given that data. I need to ofcourse, use an ng-repeat to show all these data in my bootStrap tabs.

**I want something like this:**

[image]

**Markup looks like this:**

```
<a load-data data-param="1">Load me</a>
```

The directive is calling the service and all data are inside a scope. Now the element has this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs col-lg-4 col-md-4" role="tablist">
    <li ng-repeat="data in tableData | unique: 'category'"><a href="#{{$index}}" role="tab" toggle="tab"></li>
</ul>


...

<div class="tab-content col-lg-8 col-md-8">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="contents in tableData | unique: 'category'">
         <h1>{{ contents.category }}</h1>
         <div class="tab-content-details">
             <table class="table">
                 <tr>
                     <td>{{ contents.price }}</td>
                     <td>{{ contents.productConfig.specs }}</td>
                     <td>{{ contents.productConfig.description }}</td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**But the current code gives me result looks like this:**

[image]

Each category is equivalent to one `nav-link` and one `tab-pane`. Meaning, if a category has multiple products - then the `<table>` should be on `ng-repeat` and not the `tab-pane` itself.

Here is the *sort-of* ideal markup result to achieve the goal:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs col-lg-4 col-md-4" role="tablist">
    <li class="active"><a href="#0" role="tab" toggle="tab">Category A</li>
    <li><a href="#1" role="tab" toggle="tab">Category B</li>
    ...
</ul>


...

<div class="tab-content col-lg-8 col-md-8">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade active" id="0">
         <h1>Category A</h1>
         <div class="tab-content-details">
             <table class="table">
                 <tr>
                     <td>499.00</td>
                     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                     <td>blah blah</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>479.00</td>
                     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                     <td>blah blah</td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="1">
         <h1>Category B</h1>
         <div class="tab-content-details">
             <table class="table">
                 <tr>
                     <td>1299.00</td>
                     <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
                     <td>blah blah</td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way that I can achieve the result I want with the current structure of the data? Thanks all!

Comment: you have to restructure your JSON object like first of all you have to find the unique category and push repeated category inside that category. this way you can easily achieve what you need.

Comment: Why not change the href to be the category, group the array elements by category, and id the tab content by category?

Comment: You could also filter the array itself by category, make an object that maps those filtered arrays to the categories, wrap the whole thing in a repeat that uses the (key, value) pair of the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should target the tabs as `id`'s, and you could set each tab to have the same `id` as `data.category`, not `$index`; `toggle` should be `data-toggle`, otherwise it will never work with bootstrap tabs :

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs col-lg-4 col-md-4" role="tablist">
  <li ng-repeat="data in tableData | unique: 'category'">
     <a href="#{{data.category}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
       Category {{ data.category }}         
     </a>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then you could use a nested `ng-repeat` over the same unique repeat as above, and use `ng-if` to compare the overall `data` category with the nested `content` categories :

```html
<div class="tab-content col-lg-8 col-md-8">
  <div role="tabpanel" ng-repeat="data in tableData | unique: 'category'" class="tab-pane" id="{{data.category}}">
    <div ng-repeat="content in tableData">
      <div ng-if="content.category === data.category">
        {{ content | json }}
        <hr>
      </div>     
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Now you can style each item as you want, I just render out the JSON.

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/ZtZRA2im8Wxr1TaNWfkt?p=preview**

Comment: @alleycat, you are welcome. Thank you for upvoting! I forgot to set an active tab in the plunkr, but I think this is a minor problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var app = angular.module("App", []);
                app.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope){
                        $scope.json_data ={ 
                        "result": [
    {
        category: "A",
        price: "499.00",
        productName: "AAA",
        productConfig: {
            specs: "Lorem ipsum",
            creditAllowed: false,
            description: "blah blah",
        }
    },
    {
        category: "A",
        price: "479.00",
        productName: "AAB",
        productConfig: {
            specs: "Lorem ipsum",
            creditAllowed: true,
            description: "blah blah",
        }
    },
    {
        category: "B",
        price: "1299.00",
        productName: "BBB",
        productConfig: {
            specs: "Lorem ipsum",
            creditAllowed: true,
            description: "blah blah",
        }
    },
    {
        category: "A",
        price: "359.00",
        productName: "AXX",
        productConfig: {
            specs: "Lorem ipsum",
            creditAllowed: true,
            description: "blah blah",
        }
    },
]
}               
                $scope.tableData_obj    = {}
                $scope.filterTxn        = {}
                $scope.json_data['result'].forEach(function(val){
                                if(val['category'] in  $scope.tableData_obj)
                                        return;
                                else
                                        $scope.tableData_obj[val['category']] = true;
                })
                $scope.tableData        = Object.keys($scope.tableData_obj)     
                $scope.own_filter       = function(values){
                        if(! $scope.filterTxn['values'])
                                return true;
                        if(values['category'] == $scope.filterTxn['values'])
                                return true
                        else
                                return false;   
                }
                $scope.update_filterTxn_values = function(data){
                        $scope.filterTxn['values'] = data;
                }
        })
```

```css
li.ACTIVE{
                        background:green;
                 
                }
                li{
                        list-style-type:none;
                }
                li a{
                        cursor:pointer;
                }
                                li.ACTIVE a {
                                        color:white;
                                        font-weight:700;
                                }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="AppCtrl ">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs col-lg-4 col-md-4" role="tablist">
                        <li ng-repeat="data in tableData track by $index" ng-class="{'ACTIVE':filterTxn['values'] == data}"><a   ng-click="update_filterTxn_values(data)" role="tab" toggle="tab">{{'click_here to filter_data - '+data}}</a></li>

                </ul>
                <h1>{{'Selected Category - '+filterTxn['values']}}</h1>
                <div class="tab-content col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="contents in json_data['result'] |filter:own_filter track by $index">
                         <h1>{{ contents.category }}</h1>
                         <div class="tab-content-details">
                             <table class="table">
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>{{ contents.price }}</td>
                                     <td>{{ contents.productConfig.specs }}</td>
                                     <td>{{ contents.productConfig.description }}</td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sudhakar! This is almost done, but the main problem hasn't been solved yet. It's filtering the contents but each `tab-pane` should be displayed one by one and not all of em in one.

The code above is showing all `tab-pane` for Category A. But it should be one `tab-pane` for each categories... and only the <table> will have a separate `ng-repeat` for all data under the said category. Thanks!